# SetTimeOut Property causes pop up blocker instead of new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, window.open

I am making a synchronous post to a page and in the meanwhile while I am getting the response back I am showing an loading (wait) image. In order to show the image, I am using `SetTimeout` property and showing the response in a new window. Now since I am using the `SetTimeout` property the browser thinks this window as a pop up and blocking it. I am using `window.open`.

I have tried removing the wait image and it works fine.
When I remove the loading image it all works fine.

Any suggestion on how to fool the browser?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some demo-code (JSFiddle)?

Comment: window.open must be called from the actual click event in order for the popup not to get blocked... a setTimeout breaks that chain and thus prevents the new window from opening.

Comment: thanks Dandavis, is there no way around this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to trick browser. Instead of using setTimeout, you can create a simple while loop which will do the delay. Something like this:

```
var d1 = new Date(),
    d2 = new Date(),
    timer = 500; //Milliseconds

while (d2.valueOf() < d1.valueOf() + timer) {
    d2 = new Date();
}

window.open('new_location.html', '_blank');
```

Its not pretty solution but it does the job :)

Comment: Chrome got smarter, this is same behaviour as setTimeout